# Question on two basic limit equations with trig functions

Tags: calculus, limits

Could someone please explain the reasoning behind the following two results? They appear in exercises in a book that considers them self evident, but I am missing why that is so. Thanks.

$\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\tan 6t}{6t}=1$

$\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{4t}{\sin 4t}=1$

Comment: Putting $t=0$, the limit turns into $0 \over 0$ form, which is indeterminate. So, apply L'Hospital's Rule, differentiate numerator and denominator with respect to $t$, then put $t=0$. You'll end up with $1$.

Comment: They used the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$.